# Django: aggregate or annotate function, flatten JSON and filter data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

The solution would be simple and easy, but I am not able to fetch what I want. I am trying to get the summary a summary table that has a foreign key primary key relationship and provides an array of nested JSON data, which is difficult to display in table format in the frontend. So I am trying to flatten it in the backend, add filters and fetch accordingly.

The way I am approaching would be wrong, if someone can please help, I am thankful.

**model.py**

```
class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'place'
        managed=False
        
        
class Session(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place,related_name='session',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    start = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    count = models.IntegerField()
    num_not_placed = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'session'
        managed=False


class Animal(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sess = models.ForeignKey(Session,related_name='details',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'animal'
        managed=False
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PlaceSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
  length_max = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  length_min = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  length_avg = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  length_std = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  is_active_percent = serializers.IntegerField()
  counts = serializers.IntegerField()
  Num_of_not_placed = serializers.IntegerField()
  Date = serializers.DateField()
  type = serializers.CharField()
  class Meta:
      model = place
      fields = ["Date","location","type","is_active_percent","length_max","length_min","length_avg","length_std","Num_of_not_placed","counts"]
      expandable_fields = {
        'session': (SessionSerializer, {'many': True})
      }
```

I have used flexfields serialiser, which is not working when I try to expand.

**views.py**

```
class SummaryFilter(FilterSet):
    type_filter = filters.CharFilter(method="filter_by_type")

    def filter_by_type(self,queryset,name,value):
        queryset = Place.objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('session', queryset=Countsession.objects.filter(details__type=value).distinct()),
            Prefetch('session__details', queryset=Lifeform.objects.filter(type=value).order_by('id').distinct()),)
        return queryset

class SummaryModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Place.objects.all().filter(session__details__type='shrimps')
    serializer_class = PlaceSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = SummaryFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Place.objects.values('location','session__start').annotate(total_count=Count('session__details__deformed'), def_count = Count('session__details__deformed',filter=Q(session__details__deformed=True))).values('location','session__start',def_percent = F('def_count')/F('total_count')*100).annotate(            
            counts = Count('session__details__deformed'),
            length_max=Max('session__details__length'),
            length_min=Min('session__details__length'),
            length_avg=Avg('session__details__length'),
            length_std=StdDev('session__details__length'),
            Num_of_not_placed = Sum('session__num_not_sortable'),
            Date = TruncDate('session__start'),
            type = F('session__details__type')
        )

        return queryset
```

I am currently getting the JSON format flattened like this

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2021-01-01",
        "location": "Loc 1",
        "type": "dog",
        "is_active_percent": 40,
        "length_max": "38.74",
        "length_min": "22.46",
        "length_avg": "35.48",
        "length_std": "6.51",
        "Num_of_not_placed": 0,
        "counts": 5
    },
    {
        "Date": "2021-01-02",
        "location": "Loc 1",
        "type": "dog",
        "is_active_percent": 50,
        "length_max": "43.47",
        "length_min": "43.47",
        "length_avg": "43.47",
        "length_std": "0.00",
        "Num_of_not_placed": 0,
        "counts": 4
    },
    {
        "Date": "2021-01-01",
        "location": "Loc 2",
        "type": "cat",
        "is_active_percent": 50,
        "length_max": "38.74",
        "length_min": "38.74",
        "length_avg": "38.74",
        "length_std": "0.00",
        "Num_of_not_placed": 0,
        "counts": 4
    },
    {
        "Date": "2021-01-03",
        "location": "Loc 2",
        "type": "cat",
        "is_active_percent": 0,
        "length_max": "24.45",
        "length_min": "24.45",
        "length_avg": "24.45",
        "length_std": "0.00",
        "Num_of_not_placed": 0,
        "counts": 4
    }
]
```

I am not able to expand or filter using the API, when I try with a custom based filter, I get an error saying *attempting to get a value for field `Date` on serializer `PlaceSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Place` instance. Original exception text was: 'Place' object has no attribute 'Date'.*
But I have defined the Date column as the Serialisers column. I am trying to filter based on type and group by based on location and Date (daily, weekly, monthly, yearly) separately and together that are sent in api.

Comment: Does the `Tank` model have a `Date` field? If not you need to tell the serializer how to get this field

Comment: Date, type, Num_of_not_placed  and other fields I have defined as field at the serializer level and taken from views. I am not even able to expand or filter based on type after this.

Comment: @bdbd, Any suggestion or solution, how this can be retrieved?

Comment: What is `Tank` model ?

Comment: Place model is only the Tank model. I have edited the code.

Comment: it seems you filtered queryset doesn't have a Date attribute returned.

Comment: @Yasii yes, can you please help me, what changes are to be made?

Comment: When you write a custom filter, you should not reinitiate the queryset. If you do, what happens is you'll get an entirely different queryset.

Comment: Okay, understood. But in my case, what else can I do? Because I need to get Max, Min, Avg, Std_Dev from based on location and/or date, then filter based on type.

Answer (score 0):

Filterset takes the Model so you can add Datefield to your Place model instead and use a filterset like this

```
class PlaceFilter(FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model = Place
    fields = {
        'Date': ['exact', 'range', 'in'],
        }
```

Side note:

1. Django automatically provides id field for a model you don't have to explicitly add it
2. The table name as well unless for some reason you want your table name to be different from your model name
3. It is much easier to specify all your fields in the model then use classes like ModelSerializer and the Filterset above

Cheers! All the best!

Comment: The above filter doesn't work. The date and type fields are serialiser fields. This can't be used as fields in meta. 
`TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: Date`
Got the above error.

Comment: Why can't you use them as model fields then filter as above?
That was my suggestion

Comment: Because these fields are from session and animal models. It was difficult to take data from nested JSON, so I flattened, used annotation and saved it in serialiser column.